# SolrJ-7.0.0 issue in Websphere8.5.5

Tags: solr, java-8, websphere, apache-zookeeper, solrj

I have solrj7.0 client deployed in websphere 8.5.5(JDK1.8) with fix pack 13. Initially application connects to solr 7 servers perfectly but after application restart it throws linkage error [Exception][1]

java.lang.BootstrapMethodError: java.lang.LinkageError: loading constraint vio
lation when overriding method "org/apache/zookeeper/Watcher.process(Lorg/apache/zookeeper/WatchedEvent;)V" during creation of class 
"org/apache/solr/common/cloud/ZkStateReader$$Lambda$41/00000000BB9229F0": loader "java/lang/InternalAnonymousClassLoader@77d5a3b" of
 class "org/apache/solr/common/cloud/ZkStateReader$$Lambda$41/00000000BB9229F0" and loader "com/ibm/ws/classloader/CompoundClassLoad
er@aa945a0a" of class "org/apache/zookeeper/Watcher" have different types for the method signature
                                 javax.faces.el.EvaluationException: java.lang.BootstrapMethodError: java.lang.LinkageError: loading
 constraint violation when overriding method "org/apache/zookeeper/Watcher.process(Lorg/apache/zookeeper/WatchedEvent;)V" during cre
ation of class "org/apache/solr/common/cloud/ZkStateReader$$Lambda$41/00000000BB9229F0": loader "java/lang/InternalAnonymousClassLoa
der@77d5a3b" of class "org/apache/solr/common/cloud/ZkStateReader$$Lambda$41/00000000BB9229F0" and loader "com/ibm/ws/classloader/Co
mpoundClassLoader@aa945a0a" of class "org/apache/zookeeper/Watcher" have different types for the method signature
        at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:102)
        at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:98)
        at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:315)
        at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:774)
        at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1266)
        at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:77)
        at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:97)
        at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:114)
        at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:310)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1233)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:782)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:481)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:178)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.invokeTarget(WebAppFilterChain.java:136)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:97)
        at org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter.doFilter(FileUploadFilter.java:100)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:195)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:91)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:967)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1107)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.CacheServletWrapper.handleRequest(CacheServletWrapper.java:87)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:949)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.handleRequest(WSWebContainer.java:1817)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:200)
        at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:463)
        at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:530)
        at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.processRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:316)
        at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.ready(HttpInboundLink.java:287)
        at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.sendToDiscriminators(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:2
14)
        at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.complete(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:113)
        at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:175)
        at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
        at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161)
        at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:138)
        at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:204)
        at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:775)
        at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:905)
        at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1892)
Caused by: java.lang.BootstrapMethodError: java.lang.LinkageError: loading constraint violation when overriding method "org/apache/z
ookeeper/Watcher.process(Lorg/apache/zookeeper/WatchedEvent;)V" during creation of class "org/apache/solr/common/cloud/ZkStateReader
$$Lambda$41/00000000BB9229F0": loader "java/lang/InternalAnonymousClassLoader@77d5a3b" of class "org/apache/solr/common/cloud/ZkStat
eReader$$Lambda$41/00000000BB9229F0" and loader "com/ibm/ws/classloader/CompoundClassLoader@aa945a0a" of class "org/apache/zookeeper
/Watcher" have different types for the method signature
        at org.apache.solr.common.cloud.ZkStateReader.(ZkStateReader.java:863)
        at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.ZkClientClusterStateProvider.connect(ZkClientClusterStateProvider.java:121)
        at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.CloudSolrClient.connect(CloudSolrClient.java:615)
        at search.SolrConnection.getConnection(SolrConnection.java:18)
        at search.SolrJWrapper.search(SolrJWrapper.java:291)
        at search.SolrJBean.advanceSearchSummary(SolrJBean.java:602)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:90)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:55)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:508)
        at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:268)
        at org.apache.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:278)
        at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:102)
        at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:88)
        ... 37 more

Comment: Please, add the error trace inside the question (not as image)

Comment: question updated